# How do I use an expression as the key of a `c()`?

Tags: r

In R, I can put a concatenation expression in the value of a `c()` like this:

```r
c(
  foo = paste("first", "second", "third"),
  bar = paste("1", "2"),
  baz = paste("A", "B", "C", "D")
)
```

but I can't do that with the keys (because it's not a string)

```r
# (This doesn't work)
c(
  paste("first", "second", "third") = "foo",  # Error: unexpected '='
  paste("or", "some", "other", "strings") = "someothervalue",
  "XYZ" = "baz"
)
```

is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `setNames` as `=` wouldn't allow to evaluate expression on the lhs

```
setNames("foo", paste("first", "second", "third"))
first second third 
             "foo"
```

Or another option is `eval/parse`, but it is better to use `setNames` or `names<-`

```
eval(parse(text = paste('c(', 
    dQuote(paste('first', 'second', 'third'), FALSE), '= "foo")')))
first second third 
             "foo"
```

---

although, `dplyr::lst` can do this with `:=`, so create a named list and `unlist` if we want a named vector

```
library(dplyr)
unlist(lst(!! paste("first", "second", "third") := "foo"))
first second third 
             "foo"
```

Comment: I'm trying to make a `c()` with multple key/values. How do I do `setNames()` multiple times on the same variable? I'm trying to pass a "dictionary" of headers to `httr` like this: `httr::add_headers(.headers=headers)` where parts of the header name could come from a variable, you can see it [here](https://curlconverter.com/r/) (press "POST" under "Examples:" in the top right). Sorry I don't know anything about R.

Comment: @BorisVerkhovskiy For your question in the comment, perhaps the one in the other answer with `setNames` help you

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve the desired symmetric behavior considering the `"names"` `attr`ibute.

```
`attr<-`("foo", "names", paste("first", "second", "third"))
# first second third 
#              "foo" 

`attr<-`(paste("first", "second", "third"), "names", "foo")
#                  foo 
# "first second third"
```

### *edit*

To address your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75154616/how-do-i-use-an-expression-as-the-key-of-a-c/75155085#comment132623263_75154663):

The documentation `?httr::add_headers` states that *"`.headers` can be a named character vector".* So, provided you have a list `hnames` (your "variable") you can `lapply` the `paste` over the list and name the `values` using `` `attr<-` ``,

```
httr::add_headers(.headers=`attr<-`(values, "names", lapply(hnames, paste, collapse='-')))
# <request>
# Headers:
# * Origin: http://fiddle.jshell.net
# * Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
# * Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
# * User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
# * Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
# * Accept: */*
# * Referer: http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/
# * X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
# * Connection: keep-alive
```

where of course *@akrun*'s solution with `setNames` might be simpler:

```
httr::add_headers(.headers=setNames(values, lapply(hnames, paste, collapse='-')))
# <request>
# Headers:
# * Origin: http://fiddle.jshell.net
# * Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
# * Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
# * User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
# * Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
# * Accept: */*
# * Referer: http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/
# * X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
# * Connection: keep-alive
```

---

*Data:*

```
hnames <- list("Origin", c("Accept", "Encoding"), c("Accept", "Language"
), c("User", "Agent"), c("Content", "Type"), "Accept", "Referer", 
    c("X", "Requested", "With"), "Connection")
values <- c("http://fiddle.jshell.net", "gzip, deflate", "en-US,en;q=0.8", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36", 
"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", "*/*", "http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/", 
"XMLHttpRequest", "keep-alive")
```